# SQL Query to get the Average age from multiple 'date' values

Tags: sql, average, date-arithmetic

I'm needing to get a SQL Query which returns the average age of multiple data inputs in my table

Households

| User | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002-01-01 |
| 2 | 2004-06-10 |

I want to grab both User 1 and 2 date of births and return the average age of them.

Managed to get the age from the date of births using

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Date)), '%Y') + 0 AS age
FROM Households;
```

I just can't get the rest of it working to then average the ages out.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running; is this `mysql`? Also, please show us the result that you expect for this dataset, with a short explanation of the computation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running MySQL, as the syntax of your SQL code suggests.

For starts, I would recommend simplifying the age computation. MySQL provides `timestampdiff()`, which we can use like so:

```
select user_id, user_date, 
    timestampdiff(year, user_date, current_date) age
from houshold
```

| user_id | user_date | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002-01-01 | 20 |
| 2 | 2004-06-10 | 18 |
| 3 | 2004-11-10 | 17 |

To compute the average age over all rows of the table, we can use aggregate function `avg()`:

```
select avg(timestampdiff(year, user_date, current_date)) avg_age
from houshold
```

| avg_age |
| --- |
| 18.3333 |

Here is [a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cCivfmMW) based on your sample data. Note that I renamed the columns so they do not clash with meaningful SQL names.